# Matlab.Copying the rows n times in order

Tags: matlab, row

Hey I would like to do something like the following

```
A = [...
   1 2 3
   4 5 6
   7 8 9]
```

to

```
B = [...
   1 2 3
   1 2 3
   1 2 3
   4 5 6
   4 5 6
   4 5 6
   7 8 9
   7 8 9
   7 8 9]
```

But please do not advice manual things. I am writing an algorithm with inputs and matrix dimensions may change.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways. The simplest I think would be to use the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):

```
B = kron(A, ones(3,1))
```

the faster but less readable solution is replication by multiplication and reshaping:

```
B = reshape((A(:) * ones(1,3))', 3*size(A,1),size(A,2))
```

or the same solution, but then using `repmat`:

```
B = reshape(repmat(A(:).',3,1), 3*size(A,1),size(A,2))
```

Comment: +1 you beat in 30 seconds...

Comment: Thank you, kron worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something based on the following:

```
a = [1 2 3]
b = [4 5 6]
c = [7 8 9]

d = [ a; a; b; b; c; c]

e = [ repmat([a], [2, 1]) ;
      repmat([b], [2, 1]) ;
      repmat([c], [2, 1]) ]
```

`d` and `e` both result in the matrix below:

```
=

1   2   3
1   2   3
4   5   6
4   5   6
7   8   9
7   8   9
```

To append more rows you can also use this for loop and see what the result is:

```
 e = [] 
 for i = 1:2    
      e = [ e;
            repmat([a], [2, 1]) ;
            repmat([b], [2, 1]) ;
            repmat([c], [2, 1]) ]  
 end
```